# How can I programatically take a tree of data and put it into a template?

Tags: php, json

I've designed an HTML template, and I have a bunch of data that I need to put into the template, so that it can be accessed via pagination.

My data looks like this:

```
Mazda
    Features
        - Four doors
        - Leather interior with heated seats
    Resources
        - http://example.com/
        - http://example.com/mazdarepairs
Subaru
    Features
        - Vibrant color, bright headlights
        - 35 miles per gallon on the highway
    Resources
        - http://example.com
        - http://example.com/buyasubaru
```

It's a static set of data in a Word document right now, with about 30 "cars" in it. What would be the most effective way to convert this to a better format (eg. JSON) to access in PHP? I don't need anything fancy.

Comment: you would need some kind of parser, i guess. can you show us some real data please? like a copy and paste - text of some actual cars?

Comment: If your data has some sort of meaningful delimiters, you could try to parse it into an array in PHP and encode it to JSON if you wish. Like @low_rents mentioned, it'll be easier if you showed us a format of the data

Comment: Thanks low_rents & @WeeYou You. I've included more realistic data in my OP.

Comment: FWIW, that's *almost* YAML. Tweak it a little bit to be actual YAML and you get conversion from anything to anything for free using a YAML parser in virtually any language of your choice.

Comment: @DannyF247 seems you are maybe able to parse this data by splitting it at linebreaks `\n` and tabulators `\t`. i can take a closer look at it later.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way you can approach it

- create a "Car" object (if you want to do the object-oriented approach) and an array of cars.
- Assuming features and resources are the only two properties in your data, have two arrays in the object, namely "Features" and "Resources".

Then, start reading off your data line by line.

Loop:

- If first character is not a tab (or spaces, depending on your data again), create a new car with the line as name, and add it into the array.
- Else, check if next line is "     Features". If it is not, there is inconsistent data and doc is unable to be parsed.
- If it is, the subsequent reads of the line should start with "       - ". Add all of them into your features array.
- Rinse and repeat for "Resources" array.
- End the loop upon arriving at two "\n"s or any equivalent.

This approach is obviously very tailored to your situation and will only work if your data is consistent.